# String conversion within GAE webapp template

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to create a string of the key of a `ReferenceProperty` within a [webapp](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/) template:

Assume the following simple datastore model:

```
def User(db.Model):
  first_name = StringProperty()
  last_name = StringProperty()

def Email(db.Model):
  user = ReferenceProperty(User)
  email = EmailProperty()
```

I then pass a list of Email entities to a webapp template in list named member_list.  Within the template, I want to create a string of the key of each Email entity's 'user' property for use in a URL, such as:

```
   {% for member in member_list %}
   <a href="/member_handler/{{INSERT_STRING_OF_MEMBER.USER_KEY_HERE"}}>blah</a>
```

I realize I could pass a string of the key to the template, but I would prefer to do the string conversion in template if possible; I have tried various permutations of `str()` and `_ str_` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the entity in question will be a `Member` instance, and presumably won't have a parent entity, it's much simpler (and produces nicer URLs) to use the key name or ID of the member, rather than the full string key. You can get this with `user.key().name()` (`user.key.name` in a Django template) or `user.key().id()`. Which one you need depends on whether you created the entity with a key name or not.

If you have an email object, there's no need to fetch the `User` from it just to get its key. Instead, call `Email.user.get_value_for_datastore(member)`, which will return the `Key` object of the `User` it references. You can then extract the relevant field as you wish. There's no way to do this in Django, though, so you'll either need to do it outside Django and pass it in, or add a method to the `Email` class that returns the key.

Once you have an ID or Name and want to fetch the `User` object it references, call `User.get_by_id(id)` or `User.get_by_key_name(name)` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/member_handler/{{ member.user.key }}">blah</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`member.user.key` should do the trick:

```
{% for member in member_list %}
   <a href="/member_handler/{{member.user.key"}}>blah</a>
```

Comment: @Jeff that's why I don't like Django webapp templating ; I prefer templates where I can use the Python syntax directly.

Comment: sounds appealing.  i read your question from last summer re templates....what are your top recommendations now?  i am new to web dev, and have only worked with GAE's webapp templates on a toy project.

Comment: If you're doing this in a loop, you'll go to the datastore each iteration.  You can prefetch reference properties to improve performance: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/01/ReferenceProperty-prefetching-in-App-Engine

Comment: @Jeff have a look to tipfy or kay